# org import not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am fairly new to Java and have been trying to create a JSON object for a program, but it says that the package is not accessible. Eclipse tells me that the whole org package is not accessible.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGdCj.png)

I have looked on other responses but I don't have the coding knowledge to understand their solutions. Deleting my module-info.java brought up an error when I ran my program, and I do not know how to fix it with a requires statement in the module-info.java.

Comment: Delete your launch configuration (in _Run > Run Configurations..._) and `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules). Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages are in external jars known as dependencies. Dependencies must registered in the pom.xml (for maven), the gradle file or the jar should be copied onto the classpath.

org.json is in [org.json:json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20220924)